# {{collection}} vs {{each}}

Tags: ember.js

I have a template in which I use `#each` to generate a list. The list contains a progressbar for each item, but if one moves they all move (the progressbar moves for each item, not only for the one on which I trigger the acttion).
Does that mean I should rewrite the template and the controller to use collectionView?

```
{{#each dataset in controller}}
<div class="box">
  <h3>{{dataset.data_set.name}}</h3>
  <div>
      {{view App.ProgressBar isStriped=true isAnimated=true progressBinding="progressvalue"}}
  </div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Not sure, but I think `progressBinding="progressvalue"` is binding to your controller, and not your item.

Comment: Thomas is correct. Because you're using the `in` syntax for `each` the context is the controller. `progressBinding="dataset.progressValue"` should suffice, although depending on exactly what you're doing it might be prudent to use `itemController` in this situation.